# Non-zero exit status package installation error on RStudio server

Tags: r, r-package, rstudio-server, rgdal

I've been trying to run an LGCP in 'inlabru' that was taking forever so I've been set up with a Unix account to access an RStudio server. The trouble is now I am getting non-zero exit status installation errors for a few packages. Specifically 'rgdal' and 'inlabru'. I have tried (for 'rgdal') installing the dependencies and PROJ/GDAL without any success. The end of the error is:

```
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/home/staff4/ebryce/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/rgdal’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘systemfonts’ is not available for package ‘svglite’
* removing ‘/home/staff4/ebryce/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/svglite’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘svglite’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘terra’ is not available for package ‘raster’
* removing ‘/home/staff4/ebryce/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/raster’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘raster’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘s2’, ‘units’ are not available for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/home/staff4/ebryce/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/sf’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘raster’ is not available for package ‘leaflet’
* removing ‘/home/staff4/ebryce/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/leaflet’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘leaflet’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘sf’, ‘svglite’ are not available for package ‘leafpop’
* removing ‘/home/staff4/ebryce/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/leafpop’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘leafpop’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘raster’, ‘terra’ are not available for package ‘satellite’
* removing ‘/home/staff4/ebryce/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/satellite’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘satellite’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘leaflet’, ‘raster’, ‘sf’ are not available for package ‘leafem’
* removing ‘/home/staff4/ebryce/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/leafem’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘leafem’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘leafem’, ‘leaflet’, ‘leafpop’, ‘raster’, ‘satellite’, ‘sf’ are not available for package ‘mapview’
* removing ‘/home/staff4/ebryce/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/mapview’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mapview’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp57pHoc/downloaded_packages’
```

I am thinking it is the library that is failing the installation because it's a server, but I've tried changing .libPaths() to a folder on my drive with no success. I have also tried running

```
install.packages("rgdal", type="source", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", configure.args=c('--with-gdal-config=/opt/local/bin/gdal-config'))
```

and get

```
configure: error: gdal-config not found - configure argument error.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/home/staff4/ebryce/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/rgdal’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp57pHoc/downloaded_packages’
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`gdal` (and friends) are not installed

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libudunits2-dev libgdal-dev libgeos-dev libproj-dev
```